# How to change order of PHAssetCollection list

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8, swift2, xcode7

I am using the Photos framework to fetch album list in iOS8 using this code,
how to reorder smartAlbums, so i can show 'Recently Added' on top of all

```
 let smartAlbums : PHFetchResult = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithType(PHAssetCollectionType.SmartAlbum, subtype: PHAssetCollectionSubtype.AlbumRegular, options: nil)
```

in cellForRow method

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let collection = smartAlbums[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel?.text = collection.localizedTitle
            return cell

    }
```

[image]

```
let photofetchOpt:PHFetchOptions? = PHFetchOptions()
    photofetchOpt?.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key:"localizedTitle", ascending: false)]
```

i have tried to use PHFetchOptions while fetching AssetCollections, but there is no effect on order of smartAlbums.

Answer (score 1):

`PHAssetCollection` class has a property name `startDate` which indicates the earliest creation date among all assets in the asset collection. [Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phassetcollection/1618514-startdate?language=objc).

Use `sortDescriptor` in the `PHFetchOptions` to fetch albums buy latest image order.

**Objective-C**

```
PHFetchOptions *options = [PHFetchOptions new];
options.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"startDate" ascending:NO]];
PHFetchResult<PHAssetCollection*> *allCollections = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeSmartAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAny options:nil];
```

**Swift**

```
let options = PHFetchOptions()
options.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "startDate", ascending: false)]
let result = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .smartAlbum, subtype: .any, options: options)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for reordering PHCollectionList, I am posting this answer for whom who are struggling to reorder the list
Basically i am using  `NSMutableArray sortedSmartAlbumsCollectionsFetchResults`

```
if(smartAlbums.count > 0) {
    for i in 0...smartAlbums.count-1 {
        let assetCollection:PHAssetCollection = smartAlbums[i] as! PHAssetCollection

        if assetCollection.assetCollectionSubtype == PHAssetCollectionSubtype.SmartAlbumRecentlyAdded {
            sortedSmartAlbumsCollectionsFetchResults.insertObject(assetCollection, atIndex: 0)
        }
        else {
            sortedSmartAlbumsCollectionsFetchResults.addObject(assetCollection)
        }
    }
}
```

as shown in above code, I have fetch each PHAssetCollection from smartAlbums and check if it's subtype is `SmartAlbumRecentlyAdded` if YES then insert it at 0 index else continue adding in `NSMutableArray`

see result

[image]